Overriding environment OpenAI gym registry error
To the best of my knowledge I followed this documentation for gym_examples verbatim and received this error
logger.warn(f"Overriding environment {new_spec.id} already in registry.")

I assumed it might be referencing an existing environment, so I appended "_fromtutorial" to every instance of "gym_examples" This did not fix the issue, and I have no idea what this means. Inserting this solution gave the following error,
env_dict = gym.envs.registration.registry.env_specs.copy()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'env_specs'

which I think is referencing line 434 to 499 in this source code.
Does anyone know how to fix this, or able to help me solve this?
